# Why does align="right" not work?

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment

A few days ago I was working on a classic menu. It has a logo on the left and some menu buttons on the right. This was my first try – [fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/PDkPv/). But someone from this community told me that menus normally aren't coded like that but with `<ul>`and `<li>`.

So I tried to rebuild that menu – [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/bPpbg/). Unfortunately nothing works.
My first issue is that I have the feeling that the `<div id="menubuttons">` is not located **IN** the `<div id="header">`. The second problem is that `<div id="menubuttons" align="right">` isn't aligned right as it should be.

Can you help me to get the visual result of [fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/PDkPv/) with `<ul>`and `<li>` tags?

Comment: Why did you change the coding that achieved what you wanted?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Someone told me that this is not the common way. I want to learn and understand HTML and CSS – that's why I tried to rewrite this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul` element by default  will take margin

So please add `css` like this, it will remove the default margin and padding

```
ul{margin:0; padding:0}
#menubuttons { float:right}
```

Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bPpbg/6/)

Answer (score 2):

I changed some code, try  this:
http://jsfiddle.net/WnneG/

```
<ul style="float:left;paddin:0px;margin:0px;">
                <li class="menubutton"> <a href="">Home</a>

                </li >
                <li  class="menubutton">    <a href="">Info</a>

                </li>
                <li  class="menubutton">    <a href="">Spenden</a>

                </li >
                <li  class="menubutton" align="right" style="margin-right: 20px;">  <a href="">Kontakt & Impressum</a>

                </li >
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this line of code:

```
<div id="header_logo" align="left">
      <img src="http://futurized.t15.org/fut_logo.png" style="height: 12px; z-index: 2;" />
 </div>
 <div id="header_menu" align="right">
```

with:

```
<div id="header_logo" style="float:left;">
                <img src="http://futurized.t15.org/fut_logo.png" style="height: 12px; z-index: 2;" />
            </div>
            <div id="header_menu" style="float:right;">
```

hopefully you will get your desired result if this help You please mark it as green

Answer (score 1):

See the code in the fiddles you posted. Yours tries to create a menu from divs, while the one you are trying to get to, has `<li>` items with `float: left;`

Comment: Well, the thing is: fiddle1 is working while fiddle2 isn't working…

Comment: Study the code differences, and you'll see what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put to `<li>` tag style `display:block;float:right;` like this: `<li style="display:block;float:right">`

Comment: It should, if it doesn't put to the `<div>` tag style like `text-align:left`

Answer (score 1):

Use float = right instead of align for the div menubuttons.

```
#menubuttons {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 2.5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    display: block;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a version of your menu. I think this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/yBTJF/4/

```
.menu 
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

If you want `:hover`, all you have to do is create a selector in your CSS:

```
.menu a:hover
{
    // ...
}
```